# Bootstrap: calendar invoked in a popup is in background

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to display a calendar in a popup, here is my html code (i am using the bootstrap library):

```
    <!--search & user info start-->
    <ul class="nav pull-right top-menu">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-filter" style="font-size:20px;margin:5px"></i>
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu extended logout">
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><i class=" fa fa-angle-right"></i>Temps</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</div>
</header>
<!-- Modal -->
          <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Filtre chronologique </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <p><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Personnalisée</p>
                              <div class="input-group input-large" data-date="13/07/2013" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control dpd1" name="from">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon">A</span>
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control dpd2" name="to">
                               </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>

          </div>
```

However, my calendar appears in background, how you can see in the following picture:
[image]

Do you know how I could possibly solve that ?

Thank you for your attention and your help !

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do in this situation is "move" the `modal`.

All you do is in the `#mymodal`...

```
#mymodal {
    margin-top: 100px; /*you can change this*/
    margin-left: 100px; /*you can change this*/
}
```

Another way is resizing the width and height of the modal so people don't see the calendar.

```
#mymodal {
    height: 500px; /*you can change this*/
    width: 1000px; /*you can change this*/
}
```

And now, you would not be able to see the calendar in the background.